# MongoDB Max of Count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Document structure:
userId, name, product(Array)

Requirement:
Need to find a userId who has largest number of products.

Tried to count the number product for userId using the below query 1, but not sure how to find the Max value out of it

Query 1:

```
db.things.aggregate({$project:{id:"$userId",count:{$size:{"$ifNull":["$Product",[]]}}}})
```

Result:

> Id: 1    count:0
>
> Id: 2    count:7
>
> Id: 3    count:10

End output should be like this:

> Id: 3    count:10

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do a `$sort` on `count`, than `$limit` the number of sort results to 1, to get only the document with the biggest count:

```
db.things.aggregate([ 
    {$project:{ id: "$userId", count: {$size:{"$ifNull":["$Product",[]]} } }}, 
    {$sort : {count : -1}}, 
    {$limit : 1 }
])
```

When using the ['$max'](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator, you need to do a group by `_id=null` (or other constant, all doc have to be in the same group, to compute the max out of them ), than get the max. But you cannot get the id of the user without a sort operation, in the aggregation pipeline.

```
db.things.aggregate([

    {$project:{
        id: "$userId", count: {$size:{"$ifNull":["$Product",[]]} }
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: null, 
        max: { $max: "$count" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: > db.things.aggregate({
 $project:{
  id:"$userId",count:{$size:{"$ifNull":["$Product",[]]}}
 },
 $group:{_id:null, max:{$max:"$count"}}
})
                                                                                                                               
assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.",
        "code" : 16435,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed

Comment: Try my correction. If your query is correct it should work,;I did not test it, cause you did not provide some document schema.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot !

Comment: But only concern is I am not getting the user ID, Getting the response like this ("_id" : null, "Max":10}

Comment: You can also use $sort which is the corect approach in this case. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort . Rather than $group. try this:       db.things.aggregate([
        
        {$project:{
            id: "$userId", count: {$size:{"$ifNull":["$Product",[]]} }
        }},

        {$sort : {count : -1}},
        { $limit : 1 }
    ]), and I will update my response